# How to read the geographical coordinates of a pixel in GDAL?

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, gdal

I have an image in UTM projection, given a pixel value (px, py) I'd need to get its corresponding utm coordinates (utx, utmy).
Is it possible? I tried

```
gdallocationinfo  input.tif 256 256
```

but I did not get the expected result.

Thank you

M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`gdallocationinfo` is for getting pixel values out of a raster. For conversion you should use `gdaltransform`. If you provide the target image as an argument you can enter pixel coordinates and get projected coordinates in return.

So:

```
gdaltransform input.tif
256 256
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did `gdaltransform -t_srs EPSG:32629 input_red.tif 256 256`  but I need to specify also the source spatial reference set (`gdaltransform -s-srs ? -t_srs EPSG:32629 input_red.tif 256 256`). I do not know how to reference the pixel space as the source reference.

Comment: The source reference is your image, and the target reference is the projection of the image. You dont need to specify `s_srs` or `t_srs`.

Comment: thank you, it worked! I did try your solution but I executed the whole line, I did not input the pixel values after the first line.

Comment: Yes, the working deviates a bit from the other GDAL cmd tools. For a programmatic python solution see for example:
http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Problem-with-pixel-line-coordinates-td3748877.html#a3748878

Answer (score 0):

It's a math problem, you just need to [fetch the affine transformation coefficients](https://web.archive.org/web/20180716155258/http://www.gdal.org:80/classGDALDataset.html#af9593cc241e7d140f5f3c4798a43a668), which you can easily do with the Python bindings. Also, it depends on your pixel coordinate system (e.g., does it start with [1,1] or [0,0]? And, which corner is the origin?)

Comment: it starts with [1,1]. Thank you for your link. I'd need to get the utm coordinates out of a pixel coordinates in a groovy script. I'll check the python bindings you suggest. Since I'm pretty new to these stuffs I was wondering if there is a command line instruction doing the translation without the need to wrap python code.